# How to get target state of settling Android Bottom sheet?

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

In my Android app, I want to make certain adjustments to the contents of a bottom sheet when it's collapsed. In order for everything to transition smoothly, I'd like to trigger my animations when the sheet starts settling on the collapsed state. I can easily detect that the state is `STATE_SETTLING`, but how to tell what state it's settling to? Ideally I'd like to avoid having thresholds of my own.